# Same image getting uploaded for all the options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dynamic website. I want to accept the details of different items including their image. The js is working but only for one item. The moment I add another item and I try to upload a different pic, either it does not open the dialog or it will take the same image for all the items. For single item, the code is working fine.
This is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeguajar/3/).

```
$(".file-upload").on('change', function(){
    readURL(this); 
});
$(".upload-button").on('click', function() {
    $(".file-upload").click();
});
$("#additem").click( function () {
    $(".grid").append('<div class="cell" style="overflow: hidden; visibility:;"><form><fieldset style="color:white;"><legend>Item Details</legend><img class="profile-pic" src="" /><div class="upload-button" style="cursor:pointer;">Upload Image</div></br><input class="file-upload" type="file" accept="image/*"/></br><p><input type="text" placeholder="Item name"/></br><p><input type="text" placeholder="Item category"/></br><p><input type="number" placeholder="Number of items"/></br><p><input id="itemsubmit" type="submit" class="btn" value="Add Item"/></br></fieldset></form></div>');
});
```

I feel that my js is working for only one item. If somebody can tell me where am I going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be you are dynamically adding some new controls to the form on button click.

So the newly created elements doesn't have an event listener that is the issue.

Try to change your code like this.

```
  $("body").on('change', '.file-upload', function() {
    /* Your code goes here. */
  });

  $("body").on('click', '.upload-button', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.file-upload').click();
  });
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ocoog402/1/)

Comment: Now each item is able to upload an image but when i click on Upload image for the 2nd item, the dialog is opening two times asking for a pic, after selecting, both the item pics are changing. same is for 3 or more items.

Comment: Change $(".file-upload").click(); to $(this).closest('.file-upload').click();

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click','.upload-button', function(){
    $(this).closest(".cell").find('.file-upload').click();
})
```

try with changing this code hope it will work

finally, I got the issue. You don't need readUrl function actually this function puts the same src in every `profile-pic` class instead of that I am having an alternate solution which is as below.

```
$("body").on('change', '.file-upload', function() {
    var profile = $(this).closest('.cell').find('.profile-pic');
       if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
           var reader = new FileReader();
           reader.onload = function (e) {
           $(profile).attr('src', e.target.result);
       }

       reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
});
```

Change `on change` code with above code and it will give you the same output as you required.

Also, you can minimize the code by using clone method instead of writing HTML in append.

```
$("#additem").click( function () {
    var clone = $('.grid .cell:first-child').clone();
    $(".grid").append(clone);
})
```

Comment: Nope...the upload button stops working by using $(this).closest('.file-upload').click(); line.

Comment: I think it should work properly, can u please check in the console for errors.

Comment: sorry there was my mistake in code now you can check it will work

Comment: I have applied the append(clone) thing and it works brilliantly. Thank you! :)